# React App отображается пустая страница в GitLab Pages

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, react-router, gitlab-ci

Пытаюсь задеплоить React SPA в GitLab Pages. На выходе имею пустую страницу. В приложении использую **RouterProvider** и так понимаю, что проблема в нем.

```
<html lang="ru"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin=""><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&amp;family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><title>Магазин Еда</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.273f0349.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.e5c63472.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

---

**gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```
image: node:18.14.2
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - CI=false npm run build
    - rm -rf public
    - cp build/index.html build/404.html
    - mv build public
    
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

---

**App.jsx file:**

```
const authorize = useSelector(state => state.reducer_auth.authorize);
    
  const privateRouter = createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Auth />,
      },
      {
        path: "/auth/:mode",
        element: <Auth />,
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <Auth />,
      }
    ]);

  const publicRouter = createBrowserRouter([
      {
       path: "/",
       element: <ListProduct />,
     },
     {
       path: "*",
       element: <ListProduct />,
     },
     {
       path: "/basket",
       element: <ListBasket />,
     },
     {
       path: "/product_info/:id",
       element: <ProductInfo />,
     },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">  
      <RouterProvider router={authorize ? publicRouter : privateRouter} />
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением в gitlab-ci.yml следующих строк:

```
variables:
    PUBLIC_URL: "/название-вашего-проекта"
```

```
- cp public/index.html public/404.html
```